# What's the meaning of "to outdraw" somebody?

Tags: meaning

In the lyrics of "Hallelujah" by Leonard Cohen, there's one line that has been puzzled me for a long time:

> Well, maybe there's a God above
> But all I've ever learned from love
> Was how to shoot somebody who outdrew ya

The last line, what does it mean? Does it really mean to fire on someone who abused you? Or something else? Can some explain what it means to a non-native speaker?

Comment: It is metaphorical from a duel, so it is not literally shooting someone. Given the context (Sampson and Delilah), the negative interpretation would be how to hurt somebody you loved who has already betrayed your love and hurt you.

Comment: There are likely variations, but I'm more familiar with "*was how to shoot at someone who outdrew you*".

Comment: I see, a metaphorical duel

Answer (score 3):

It probably refers to the act of drawing a gun faster than someone else.

Comment: In context, it's probably not, literally, referring to a gunfight.

Comment: As in: Cohen was usually the one to be broken up with, rather than to break up a relationship, and this was how he dealt with it, by shooting them down.